# How to mount a disk that was not ejected properly?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, mount

I am using OSX El Capitan 10.11.2

I have an external Western Digital of 1TB

When I ejected I did not do with the properly way and now I am not able to mount

I can see the disk here

[image]

But when I open the disk utility it gets stuck here

[image]

Anyone has faced something similar?

Thank you

Comment: By default OS X can only mount an NTFS volume as Read Only and therefore unmounting it improperly shouldn't be a problem. However if it was mounted Read/Write using an `fstab` entry and or a third-party NTFS Write Driver then it could have cause filesystem corruption when unmounting it improperly. Have you tried running `chkdsk /f <drive>:` e.g., `chkdsk /f e:` from a Windows system using an Administrator Command Prompt and then tried mounting it under OS X again?  BTW There has been several recent posts re: NTFS and OS X 10.11.2 and there may be bug in it mounting NTFS volumes with 10.11.2.

Comment: @user3439894 thank you for your comment. Is there another way to try that? I do not have a computer with windows, I have one with ubuntu. Thank you

Comment: Personally I'd only trust fixing an NTFS volume on a Windows system as it is after all Microsoft's technology however there are utilities that can be installed under Ubuntu or other Linux Distros that can preform some repair operations.  That said this takes the discussion off topic for Ask Different and suggest you post to http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/ for help with repairing an NTFS volume under Linux.